# is it possible to input android program using electronic keyboard?

Tags: android, midi, midi-interface

I'm trying to make composition that can get data from electoronic keyboard(synthesizer, digital piano).

So I'm wondering, is it possible and how can i get the data from it.
If you have an expierence with programing composition for computer, i would like get your help.

thanks guys!

Comment: Connecting to/from an electronic keyboard is through a MIDI interface. That should be enough to get you started with your favorite search engine. StackOverflow is geared toward specific questions while this one is a bit general.